# Vectorized floating point rounding using NEON

Tags: floating-point, arm, rounding, neon

I've got a NEON register filled with `float32`. I'd like to round them to the nearest integer without having to transfer back to the main CPU. The NEON instructions to convert `float32` to `uint32` simply truncate, so e.g. `39.7` becomes `39`, not `40`. I don't care much about how `0.5` gets handled -- round away from zero or round to even both work for me.

The best path I can see to implement rounding is to

- convert to `int32` (thus truncating)
- convert *back* to `float32`
- add 1 to the `int32`, convert back to `float32`, and set aside in case we're rounding up
- subtract
- compare to `0.5` (no need for abs value since I know in my case they'll all be positive)
- select truncated or truncated + 1 based on the comparison outcome

That seems ugly, slow, and complicated.

Is there a cleaner, faster, simpler, saner way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add .5 and convert to integer. If you want the result in floating-point format, convert back.

Since you know the numbers are all positive, another option is to add 0x1p23 and subtract 0x1p23. The result of adding 0x1p23 is at least 0x1p23, so the float result has no bits with value less than one, so it must have been rounded to an integer. Then subtracting 0x1p23 subtracts the value that was added, leaving only the effect of rounding.

Update: This second method fails if the input is in [0x1p47, 0x1p48) and its low bit is one. Then 0x1p23 is half the ULP of the input, so the addition causes rounding upward (to even), and the subtraction has no effect. I think there is a modification to fix that, but I do not have it at hand.

Comment: Hahahaha. I am an idiot. :) And thanks for the 0x1p23 tip, that's interesting.

Comment: Actually, 0x1p23 results in an incorrect result if the input is in [0x1p47, 0x1p48) and its low bit is one. Then 0x1p23 is half the ULP of the input, so the addition causes rounding upward (to even), and the subtraction has no effect. I think there is a modification to fix that, but I do not have it at hand.

Comment: I think the value that is to be added and subtracted is 0x1.8p+23

Comment: @kanna: 0x1.8p+23 does not work with x = 0x1p22 + 1 (4,194,305). Then x + 0x1.8p+23 would be 0x2p24 + 1 (16,777,217) with real arithmetic, but that is not representable, so 0x2p24 (16,777,216) is produced. Then subtracting 0x1.8p23 gives 0x1p22 (4,194,304).

Answer (score 0):

Float to int round needs to add or subtract 0.5 depending on the positive or negtive, we knew. In Neon, 1. I can extract the signed of value; 2. bit-or with 0.5, then 0.5 has the sign; 3. add signed 0.5 with origin value:

```
// 1. extract sign of origin value
int32x4_t reinterpretInt = vreinterpretq_s32_f32(inputFloat);
int32x4_t signExtract = vdupq_n_s32(-2147483648);
int32x4_t signSignal = vandq_s32(reinterpretInt, signExtract);

// 2. bit-or with 0.5 with origin value
float32x4_t roundValue = vdupq_n_f32(0.5);
float32x4_t plusValue = vreinterpretq_f32_s32(vorrq_s32(vreinterpretq_s32_f32(roundValue), signSignal));

// 3. add signed 
return vaddq_f32(inputFloat, plusValue);
```